# Unable to show view in debug mode eclipse luna

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-luna

I recently switched to eclipse luna(windows 64bit) for android.

I not able to add any new view in debug mode, which makes the debugging inconvenient.Although in java mode I'm able to add views!

[image]

I tried searching but did not find any solution.

Please help !

Comment: have you tried with *open perspective* ?

Comment: Looks like you have maximized the code view, double click the 'xxx.java' tab to restore the views.

Comment: @blackbelt Ya tried debug using open perspective .Same issue

Comment: @greg-449 I tried double clicking java class ,but did not help

Comment: It has to be the tab at the top of the editor, not the text. Or click the small 'Restore' button at the right (just below DDMS in your screen shot).

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: @Adrian ya ..i did , right click on debug button and click reset .You will have the default perspective again